# The deeplink is not opened properly when I run it via Terminal with ADB

Tags: android, testing, command-line, adb, deeplink

This is my deeplink:  `example://editor?photo-id=217762275004202&component=crop`

In the deeplink it is shown that should open app then open photo then crop tool

When I copy this into terminal line it opens only photo. The crop tool does not open (This part of deeplink does not work: - `&component=crop` )

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d example://editor?photo-id=217762275004202&component=crop
```

Also, when I click on the deeplink right from device it opens properly but from command line - not! .

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use quotes to properly escape special characters:

```sh
adb shell 'am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://editor?photo-id=217762275004202&component=crop"'
```